# AWS Load balancer OutOfService, Instance though InService

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

Followed the entire tutorial at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/wah-linux/getting-started-create-as.html and the problem I am having is with the load balancer.

According to the Instances page and the Auto Scaling Groups page, the two instances I am running are InService and Healthy.

On the Load Balancers page under the Instances tab for the load balancer, it lists each instance as OutOfService and each Availability Zone's Health status as "No (Availability Zone contains no healthy instances)".

The part that is most confusing to me (and I believe to be the main issue) is that when I visit one of the instance's at its public dns ec2-server-name.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com, it displays the default "Amazon Linux AMI Test Page" but **the headers of the page return 403.**

So I imagine the issue is that the load balancer is running its health check and seeing that the instance's returned status code is 403. Why is it returning a 403 error code though? When I load the instance in browser I can see the page and everything seems to work, but when I visit the load balancer all I get is a blank white page.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I thought that might be the case initially, but Stack Overflow already has a lot of questions in regards to similar subject material (Just looking at the side column's "Related" section shows this)

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the issue. Amazon's default "Amazon Linux AMI Test Page" returns a 403 error by default. Once new files are uploaded to /var/www/html and replace the default page, the problem goes away.